# Actionscript 3: Error #1009: Cannot access a property or method of a null object reference. (parent)

Tags: actionscript-3, class, package, parent, addchild

This is a bit difficult to explain, but I will try.

In my Main() class, let's say  I have the main movieclip (bg_image) being created, and also some lines that create an instance of another class. (look at the code below)

```
var route = Route(Airport.return_Route);
```

This route instance, is then purposed to dynamically add sprite-childs to the main background from the Main() class.

I have tried to to this with the following line:
`new_flight = new Flight(coordinates)`
`Main.bg_image.addChild(new_flight);`

This seem to work pretty fine. Let's switch focus to the new_flight instance. At the Flight class, this line `trace(this.parent)` would return "[object Image]".I would consider this successful so far since my intention is to add the new_flight as child to bg_image, which I guess is an "object image".

The problem, however, occurs when trying to delete the "new_flight"-instance. Obviously the ideal way of doing this would be through bg_image with removeChild.

But, when my script reaches this line: `Main.bg_image.removeChild(this)`, my script stops and returns `ArgumentError: Error #2025: The supplied DisplayObject must be a child of the caller.`, at that line. I have also tried replacing `Main.bg_image.removeChild(this)` with `this.parent.removeChild(this)`, with no luck.

I think the solution may be to use some sort of "EventDispatching"-method. But I haven't fully understood this concept yet...

The code follows. Please help. I have no idea how to make this work...

**Main class:**

```
package 
{
import flash.display.MovieClip;
import flash.utils.Dictionary;
import flash.events.MouseEvent;
import flash.display.Sprite;
import flash.text.TextField;
import fl.controls.Button;
import flash.display.DisplayObject;

import Airport;

public class Main extends Sprite
{       
    // ------------------------
    // Buttons

    public var create_new_route;
    public var confirm_new_route;

    // images
    public static var bg_image:MovieClip;
    public var airport:MovieClip;
    //-------------------------------

    public var routeArray:Array;

            public static var airportDict:Dictionary = new Dictionary();
    public static var collectedAirportArray:Array = new Array();


    public function Main()
    {
        addEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, init);

        create_new_route = new Button();
        create_new_route.label = "Create new route";
        create_new_route.x = 220;
        create_new_route.y = 580;
        this.addChild(create_new_route)
        create_new_route.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, new_route)


        confirm_new_route = new Button();
        confirm_new_route.label = "Confirm route";
        confirm_new_route.x = 220;
        confirm_new_route.y = 610;
        this.addChild(confirm_new_route)
        confirm_new_route.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, confirm_route)
    }

    public function init(e:Event):void
    {
        removeEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, init);

        bg_image = new Image();
        addChild(bg_image);

        S_USA["x"] = 180.7;
        S_USA["y"] = 149.9;
        S_USA["bynavn"] = "New York";

        S_Norway["x"] = 423.7;
        S_Norway["y"] = 76.4;
        S_Norway["bynavn"] = "Oslo";

        S_South_Africa["x"] = -26;
        S_South_Africa["y"] = 146;
        S_South_Africa["bynavn"] = "Cape Town";

        S_Brazil["x"] = 226;
        S_Brazil["y"] = 431.95;
        S_Brazil["bynavn"] = "Rio de Janeiro";

        S_France["x"] = 459.1;
        S_France["y"] = 403.9;
        S_France["bynavn"] = "Paris";

        S_China["x"] = 716.2;
        S_China["y"] = 143.3;
        S_China["bynavn"] = "Beijing";

        S_Australia["x"] = 809.35;
        S_Australia["y"] = 414.95;
        S_Australia["bynavn"] = "Sydney";

        // ----------------------------------------------------

        airportDict["USA"] = S_USA;
        airportDict["Norway"] = S_Norway;
        airportDict["South Africa"] = S_South_Africa;
        airportDict["Brazil"] = S_Brazil;
        airportDict["France"] = S_France;
        airportDict["China"] = S_China;
        airportDict["Australia"] = S_Australia;

        for (var k:Object in airportDict)
        {
            var value = airportDict[k];
            var key = k;
            startList.addItem({label:key, data:key});
            sluttList.addItem({label:key, data:key});
            var airport:Airport = new Airport(key,airportDict[key]["bynavn"]);
            airport.koordinater(airportDict[key]["x"], airportDict[key]["y"]);
            collectedAirportArray.push(airport);
            airport.scaleY = minScale;
            airport.scaleX = minScale;
            bg_image.addChild(airport);
        }

        // --------------------------------------------
        // --------------------------------------------
        // -----------------------------------------------


    }


    private function new_route(evt:MouseEvent):void
    {
        Airport.ROUTING = true;
    }

    public function confirm_route(evt:MouseEvent):void
    {
        Airport.ROUTING = false;
        trace(Airport.return_ROUTE);
        var route = new Route(Airport.return_ROUTE); // ***
        this.addChild(route); // **
        Airport.return_ROUTE = new Array();
    }

}
}
```

**Airport class:**

```
package 
{
import flash.display.MovieClip;
import flash.events.MouseEvent;
import flash.events.Event;
import flash.display.SimpleButton;
import flash.display.Stage;
import flash.text.TextField;
import flash.text.TextFormat;
import flashx.textLayout.formats.Float;

public class Airport extends MovieClip
{

    public static var ROUTING = false;
    public static var return_ROUTE:Array = new Array();
    //-----------------------------------------------------------------------------

    // ----------------------------------------------------------------------------

    protected var navn:String;
    protected var bynavn:String;

    // ----------------------------------------------------------------------------

    public function Airport(navninput, bynavninput)
    {
        this.bynavn = bynavninput;
        this.navn = navninput;

        this.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, clickHandler);
        this.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_OVER, hoverHandler);
    }

    public function zoomHandler():void
    {
        trace("testing complete");
    }

    public function koordinater(xc, yc)
    {
        this.x = (xc);
        this.y = (yc);
    }

    private function clickHandler(evt:MouseEvent):void
    {
        trace(ROUTING)

        if (ROUTING == true)
        {
            return_ROUTE.push([this.x, this.y])
        }
    }

    private function hoverHandler(evt:MouseEvent):void
    {
        if (ROUTING == true)
        {
            this.alpha = 60;
            this.width = 2*this.width;
            this.height = 2*this.height;
            this.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_OUT, awayHandler);
        }
    }

    private function awayHandler(evt:MouseEvent):void
    {
            this.width = 13;
            this.height = 13;
    }




}
}
```

**Route class**

```
package 
{

import flash.events.TimerEvent;
import flash.utils.Timer;
import flash.display.MovieClip;
import Main;

public class Route
{
    public var income:Number;
    public var routePoints:Array;
    private var routeTimer:Timer;
    private var new_flight:Flight;

    public function Route(route_array:Array)
    {
        this.routePoints = route_array
        routeTimer = new Timer(2000);// 2 second
        routeTimer.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER, route_function);
        routeTimer.start();
    }

    private function route_function(event:TimerEvent):void
    {
        for (var counter:uint = 0; counter < routePoints.length - 1; counter ++)
        {   
            trace("Coords: ", routePoints[counter][0],routePoints[counter][1],routePoints[counter + 1][0],routePoints[counter + 1][1]);
            new_flight = new Flight(routePoints[counter][0],routePoints[counter][1],routePoints[counter + 1][0],routePoints[counter + 1][1]);
            Main.bg_image.addChild(new_flight);

            var checkTimer:Timer = new Timer(15);// 1 second
            checkTimer.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER, check_function);
            checkTimer.start();

            function check_function(event:TimerEvent):void
            {
                if (new_flight.finished = true)
                {
                    checkTimer.stop();
                }
            }
        }
    }

}

}
```

**Flight class**

```
package 
{
import flash.display.MovieClip;
import flash.display.Sprite;
import flash.events.MouseEvent;
import flash.events.Event;
import flash.display.SimpleButton;
import flash.display.Stage;
import flash.events.TimerEvent;
import flash.utils.Timer;
import fl.controls.Button;
import flash.display.DisplayObject;

public class Flight extends MovieClip

{
    public static var speed:uint = 1
    public var finished:Boolean = false;

    protected var absvector:Number;
    protected var vector:Array;
    protected var myTimer:Timer;
    //protected var parentContainer:MovieClip;

    protected var utgangspunkt_x;
    protected var utgangspunkt_y;
    protected var destinasjon_x;
    protected var destinasjon_y;

    protected var vector_x;
    protected var vector_y;

    public function Flight(utgangspunkt_x, utgangspunkt_y, destinasjon_x, destinasjon_y):void
    {
        addEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, init);           
        this.utgangspunkt_x = utgangspunkt_x;
        this.utgangspunkt_y = utgangspunkt_y;

        this.x = utgangspunkt_x;
        this.y = utgangspunkt_y;    

        this.destinasjon_x = destinasjon_x + 10;
        this.destinasjon_y = destinasjon_y + 10;

        this.vector_x = Math.abs(this.destinasjon_x-this.utgangspunkt_x);
        this.vector_y = Math.abs(this.destinasjon_y-this.utgangspunkt_y);

        this.height = 20;
        this.width = 20;
    }

    public function init(evt:Event):void
    {
        trace(this.parent)
        if (utgangspunkt_x < destinasjon_x)
        {
            this.rotation = -(Math.atan((utgangspunkt_y-destinasjon_y)/(destinasjon_x-utgangspunkt_x)))/(Math.PI)*180;
        }
        else
        {
            this.rotation = 180-(Math.atan((utgangspunkt_y-destinasjon_y)/(destinasjon_x-utgangspunkt_x)))/(Math.PI)*180;
        }

        absvector = Math.sqrt(Math.pow((destinasjon_x - utgangspunkt_x),2) + Math.pow((utgangspunkt_y - destinasjon_y),2));
        vector = [(destinasjon_x - utgangspunkt_x) / absvector,(utgangspunkt_y - destinasjon_y) / absvector];

        stage.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, movement)
    }

    private function movement(evt:Event):void
    {
        if (this.vector_x > this.vector_y)
        {
            if (destinasjon_x>utgangspunkt_x)
            {
                if (this.x < destinasjon_x)
                {
                    this.x +=  speed*vector[0];
                    this.y -=  speed*vector[1];
                }
                else
                {
                    finished = true
                    Main.bg_image.removeChild(this)
                }
            }
            else if (destinasjon_x<utgangspunkt_x)
            {
                if (this.x > destinasjon_x)
                {
                    this.x +=  speed*vector[0];
                    this.y -=  speed*vector[1];
                }
                else
                {
                    finished = true
                    Main.bg_image.removeChild(this)
                }
            }
        }
        else
        {
            if (destinasjon_y>utgangspunkt_y)
            {
                if (this.y < destinasjon_y)
                {
                    this.x +=  speed*vector[0];
                    this.y -=  speed*vector[1];
                }
                else
                {
                    finished = true
                    Main.bg_image.removeChild(this)
                }
            }
            else if (destinasjon_y<utgangspunkt_y)
            {
                if (this.y > destinasjon_y)
                {
                    this.x +=  speed*vector[0];
                    this.y -=  speed*vector[1];
                }
                else
                {
                    finished = true
                    Main.bg_image.removeChild(this)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
}
```

Comment: What error you are getting?

Comment: I'm not getting an error until I try to delete the new_flight through its parent (removeChild), which should be bg_image. I've tried to trace the value of its parents, and it's shown as "null".

Comment: Are you sure `new_flight` instance is created?

Comment: Yes, I see airplanes on my screen :)

Answer (score 0):

I am confused what your asking and what your trying to do, but I will give it my best shot.

```
 this.addchild(new_class2)
```

This line adds your object to the display list. Adding another object to the display is done the same way you added the first. Flash adds objects in the sequentially, so the objects you want in the back need to be declared and added first.

This is probably what you want:

```
var new_flight:Flight = new Flight(); 
this.addchild(new_flight);
```

Also you forgot your type declaration for Class2:

```
var new_class2:Class2 = new Class2();
```

Comment: No, I don't want to add new_flight to the class2 instance.

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing:

```
Main.bg_image.addChild(new_flight);
```

with

```
Main(this.parent).bg_image.addChild(new_flight);
```

... assuming the 'main' class you refer to is infact named 'Main' and it has a named instance called 'bg_image'

Please leave a comment if it works, I can explain in more detail what is actually happening here.

Comment: This gave me the error: 1119: Access of possibly undefined property parent through a reference with static type Class2

Comment: @user3257755 can you add as much of your code to your original question as possible, including the Main class, Class2, etc. My guess is that you are trying to access the `.parent` object before you have added the actual item to the stage.

Comment: I added the code now. There may be some "trash" code for testing purposes that I forgot to remove.

Answer (score 0):

Why you are adding `new_flight` to `bg_image`?

Anyway, if you are adding `new_flight` to `bg_image`, then you have `bg_image` already declared as public static (which I do not recommend),

Try removing the flight in your `Flight` class it-self like so,

`Main.bg_image.removeChild(this)` // *

You can also use `Event Dispatching` instead of declaring `bg_image` as `static`.

If you want to remove flight then dispatch event from Flight class to Route class and there you again dispatch event to main class.

And, inside main class capture this event and access the `MovieClip`.

Comment: Of course :) I had some problems with it due to bad connection. Could you please elaborate further regarding the problems with declaring bg_image as static?

Comment: EDIT: This doesn't work afterall; I edited a class file at wrong directory.. sorry

Comment: Have you changed your `package` structure? I am assuming you have all the classes in the same directory. If it's in different directory, then add import statement in `Flight` class w.r.t your directory structure.

Comment: They are all in the same directory.

Comment: Have you changed the `static` variable?

Comment: What do you mean? I still use bg_image as a public static var. I guess this isn't optimal, but I simply could not understand the use of the EventDispatcher solution you proposed. I would be glad if you could give a further explaination on it. Thanks for helping me out :)